# How to output something before i return the view?

Tags: spring-mvc, controller

I'm working with the spring mvc, and have the following problem:

This is for a specific view:

The controller instansiates an object (from now on, called listenObject) which runs a thread that listens for a response from a server.
Right now, the controller returns a json object (to the view) if the listenObject have received a response from the server.

Here is what i need:
I need the view to show some kind of response that it has been reached.

It is impossible to return anything to the view before i instansiate the listenObject, because then the listenObject won't be instansiated.

Is it some how possible to show anything on the view, before the controller return anything to it?

Thanks in advance, and i hope you understand what im asking for.

Comment: Do you have some example code from your controller which might help illustrate your problem?

Comment: I'll think i'll just work it out by init the object in a thread.

Answer (score 0):

If you think about it you will realize it doesn't work the way you think. A view is actually a HTTP response send back to the client. Unless you're using some kind of server-side pushing (like pubsubhubub) you won't be able to achieve this.

I would approach the problem from the client side instead. Perhaps you can utilize a javascript which asynchronously polls your controller and render the progress in any way you like.